# how to get selchange msg from popUp owner draw ListBox in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to make my own custom property grid. I have made the owner-draw ListBox. when we click on the dialog box it popup.

but not getting msg when I click on the list.
how to get it?

I am trying with this function but not getting any trigger here when we click on any item on Listbox.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(x_ListBox, CListBox)
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(LBN_SELCHANGE, &x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    void x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange()
    {
        try
        {
            auto selIdx = GetCurSel();
            ReleaseCapture();
            GetParent()->DestroyWindow();
        }
        catch (CException* p)
        {
            p->Delete();
        }
    }
```

I need to send msg to the DialogBox current selected item. is there any way I can get msg from DialogBox when we select an item in ListBox. like ComboBox in the DialogBox `m_com.GetLbText(xxx);`

Comment: I think you need `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT` instead of `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT`

Comment: it is used in CListCtrl, I did not find any example using CListBox. and I check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn062-message-reflection-for-windows-controls?view=vs-2019 
also it gives 
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT( wNotifyCode , memberFxn ) 
afx_msg void memberFxn ( NMHDR * pNotifyStruct , LRESULT* result );
don't know how to use in CListBox.

Comment: Well, for starters, your `OnLbnSelchange` method is declared wrong. Per the same doc you linked to, it needs to be declared as `void x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange(NMHDR* pNotifyStruct, LRESULT* result)` instead.

Comment: In most instanced you can use the classwizard etc. to add handlers and it will create the method with the right parameters.

Comment: i change it as you said and in MessageMap also I change it, still not getting any msg in function.
on message map
// ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(LBN_SELCHANGE, &x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange)
  ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, &x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange)

in function
void x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange(NMHDR* pNotifyStruct, LRESULT* result)

Comment: You can try `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX` instead of `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT`, and return `FALSE` in the handle function.Also, refer to  the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-selchange), you need to make sure that this list box has `LBS_NOTIFY` style.

Comment: is that possible to refer some code? really getting hard. what to do.

Comment: Just change `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT` to `ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX` and return false in this handle function.

Comment: ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, &x_ListBox::OnLbnSelchange) // function give error.. i think I am missing something on it.

Comment: I am not sure whether your message mapping is correct, maybe you can use class wizard directly

Comment: hello guys the problem is solved. it can be used with  ON_CONTROL_REFLECT.
but it needed to add  
 if (message == WM_CAPTURECHANGED)
  {
   SetCapture();
  } 
in WindowProc. and it works now perfectly.
so Thank you all of you for helping me. thanks a lot a lot to all.